# Is my php codes safe?

Tags: php, include, get, require, unsafe

Is my php codes safe ?

```
<?php

$item = (int)$_GET['item'];

if (!isset($_GET['item'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}

$fileName = "items/" . $item . ".php";

if (file_exists($fileName)) {
    require_once ("items/" . $item . ".php");
} else {
    header('Location: index.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: Iam using get method with require_once :)

Comment: I would trust is_numeric() more than just casting it

Comment: @rcapote What do you mean? `(int)` is safe if you want to cast it to an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may use [is_int()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.is-int.php) instead of casting. But your code seems fine to me.

You should handle exception messages with a ExceptionHandler.

Check if $_GET is defined **before** trying to access $_GET['item'].

Comment: "if $_GET is defined" ? what do you mean ? how can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

For better security, I think it should be better if you add validation on item:

```
$valid_items = array('item1', 'item2', 'item3');

if(in_array($item, $valid_items)) {
  // something if item is valid item
}
```

Comment: based on his code, I don't think that would be viable, because he may not know what were the valid items at runtime

Comment: That's what I was about to write, until I noticed that `$item` is an integer. So in this case, there is no need for validation (since a cast to an integer makes it impossible to pass values like `..\..\..\protected-directory\index`).

Comment: @MainMa give me some example of _working_ string literal that would result in something like that. All that I tried results in 0 when casted as int.

Comment: Yeh, I know the item is integer. I keep post the answer just in case as suggestion. But on my mind was, I thought weird if we require files but don't know what the content on those files, since it also parsed by PHP. We can skip item validation if we only stream it to the user without any parsing on server side.

Comment: agree. But we don't know the context and why there is a need to do such a thing. And personally, I can't even imagine why somebody would do it, instead of having a single PHP file for every item and calling `item.php?i=123`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check first for the type of request method, something like

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'GET') { 
       header('Location: index.php'); exit; 
}


if (!isset($_GET['item'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
 }

 $item = (int)$_GET['item']; 
/*
 * just make sure that all you pass is numeric before typecasting it. If you're not                                           
 * sure...you can do this 
 * $item = is_numeric($_GET['item']) ? (int)$_GET['item'] : null; //or 0
 *
 */

 //your code here
```